# compare 3 arrays. quiz app. How to show wrong answers first?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have three arrays:

```
NSArray *Q = [1+1, 2+2, 3+3, 4+4, 5+5]; 
NSArray *A = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]; 
NSArray *UserAnswers = [2, 4, 10, 17, 26];
```

In a tableview I want to show the results but the wrong answers(in this case 10,17,26) must be shown before the correct answers(At top of the tableView).

I post it here because I need a clean and smart solution to solve this. Any ideas?

this is the dirty way, Anyone know an easier/cleaner way?

```
 NSMutableArray *wrongs = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *rights = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *dataSource = [NSMutableArray new]; 

for (int x = 0; x<questions.count; x++) {
    NSDictionary *temp = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:[questions objectAtIndex:x],@"q",[answers objectAtIndex:x],@"a",[userAnswers objectAtIndex:x], "ua", nil];

    if ([[userAnswers objectAtIndex:x]isEqual:[answers objectAtIndex:x]]) 
        [rights addObject:temp]; 
    else
        [wrongs addObject:temp]; 
}

[dataSource addObjectsFromArray:wrongs]; 
[dataSource addObjectsFromArray:rights]; 

[wrongs release]; 
[rights release];
```

Comment: Your way looks reasonable clean? Perhaps add answers to the correct arrays as the user answers?
You are leaking `temp` at the minute btw, and possibly `datasource`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was just wondering. please copy your comment and post it as an answer. I know about the leaking. dataSource is actually declared in the header file. Its just for showing purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From comments**

Your way looks reasonably clean; perhaps add answers to the correct arrays as the user answers?